# android app : getting installed applications sizes

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Java and Android app development.
I am trying to read the Total size of applications installed. as per some suggestions on this site I have used the PackageStats method of reading the sizes like below

```
       for (ApplicationInfo apInfo: installedApps) {
        if ((apInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == 0) {
            Method getPackageSizeInfo = mPackageManager.getClass().getMethod(
                    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

            getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(mPackageManager, item.applicationInfo.packageName, new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
                @Override
                public void onGetStatsCompleted(final PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                        throws RemoteException {
                        AppSize = pStats.codeSize + pStats.cacheSize + pStats.dataSize
                                + pStats.externalCodeSize + pStats.externalCacheSize + pStats.externalDataSize
                                + pStats.externalMediaSize + pStats.externalObbSize;
```

}
totalAppSize = totalAppSize+AppSize;

Note: I acquire a semaphore and release at the end of the read loop.
The totalAppSize is  different in every run of the function. Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: i will post an answer to this :) i am just testing the method you only have a little mistake in your code

Comment: I have those changes already. I am able to read the sizes however the sizes are little different in each invocation which is puzzling

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your manifest file you need to give permission of

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/>
```

once you are done follow these steps

Android Studio
•   Right click on your project New > Folder > AIDL Folder

•   Press Finish

•   Right click on aidl folder New > Package

•   Insert android.content.pm and press OK

•   Download [IPackageStatsObserver.aidl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.aidl)

•   Copy the aidl file inside the android.content.pm package

•   Build > Rebuild Project

after you are done with this you only need to get pstats.codeSize

```
   try {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

        Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

        getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms",
                new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                            throws RemoteException {

                        Log.i("TEST", "codeSize: " + pStats.codeSize);
                    }
                });
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

as you can see it in the official android [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageStats.html) that pstatus.codeSize returns the size of apk installed however there are other ways around. i have tested it and it works for me

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks Umer Kiani for your response.